# I want to keep my source protected on my development machine, how would I deploy ASP.NET MVC to the server?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, deployment, windows-server-2008

I'm not exactly sure what to do, normally I do a commit to SVN and Cruise Control does all this stuff on the server to pull from the repo and deploy everything.

However I am just playing around for fun with my personal VPS and want to know how I can from Visual Studio 2010 (web express) on my local machine just make some kind of installer or DLL or whatever and how to deploy it to my VPS of Windows Server 2008.

Do I upload via FTP and run something or place some files in a certain location and configure through IIS? Or is there some way Visual Studio can just interface with my server and impregnate it with my beautiful code?

Comment: "Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to generally relate to programming or software development in some way..." I would argue that this is quite related to software development, how else would you stage an environment to run your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description given, I'd recommend 2 options:

- check whether your server installation currently supports one-click publishing. It's likely an IIS configuration task(s) and/or ensuring your server supports [MSDeploy/WebDeploy](http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy). See ["One-Click Publishing - What's New".](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2010/04/20/one-click-publish-what-s-new-since-beta-2.aspx) Publish Use Visual Studio 2010's Publish command to perform a Web Deploy of your solution.
- setup an FTP server on your server. Use Visual Studio 2010's Publish command with the FTP option to push your built solution.

Answer (score 0):

Would this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31kztyey.aspx) help?

The thing is there's capabilities in Visual studio that can publish a web application on a web server.

But you can always do an [xcopy deployment](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B326355&x=12&y=16) as well. And since you've obviously never deployed a web application yet maybe it would be good to learn something and actually deploy it manually.

Comment: Yeah the most I have really done is do an SVN checkout on the server and go into IIS and configure everything, but I need to launch Visual Studio on the server to compile it at that point as the SVN contains the source. Having an output of compiled files I can FTP and do the same with would be ideal as well, I have never been a fan of automated stuff, especially from Microsoft.